# ESP32 bootloader circuit exchange with MOSFET:s

Tags: mosfet, bjt, switching, bootloader, switching-transients

I was looking at ESP32 documentation typical application setup, I researched the schematic below which has been referenced and discussed as a time sensistive circuit using the capacitor to delay en to reach treshold so boot can be pulled low.

My question, however, can the function of this circuit not be replaced with mosfets, removing two resistors. Or am I missing something, a transients or timing issue, etc.?
It looks to me like they should behave the same.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFQpKZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: By using a FET or MOSFET you won't get rid of the resistors, you'll probably even need two additional ones. One in series to the gate to prevent ringing (the gate of a FET is a capacitive load) and another one to GND to get rid of spurious charges that would lead to unwanted switching of the FET if DTR and/or RTS are open.

Comment: Ah, indeed, did not consider the step response. How do chips or logic gates deal with this, from the little I know I thought they were only comprised of transistors?

Comment: this would be a good question in itself :) I can't give you a true answer but I quess it has to do with the fact that on chip you have really low inductances, short paths and can control for that stuff... and if you need some resistance you make a connection in a polysilocon layer instead of a metal one.